# Rails 3: Linking to Image in New Window

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to display text that links to a image that opens a new window (_target), but I don't know the Rails 3 way of doing that.  All of my searches have just yielded making the image the link (ie link to(image_tag....)), but that's not what I want to do.

What I'm looking to do is display the text link "Click here to see an example" to the image "example.gif" in my assets/images folder.

I tried:

`<%= link_to "Click here to see an example", image_tag("example.gif"), :target => "_blank" %>`

but that didn't work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this :

```
<%= link_to "Click here to see an example", image_path("example.gif"), :target => "_blank" %>
```